# i'm facing problem in rebuilding navit... i want to enable qml? please help me out

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, navigation

how to enable qml in navit...
< gui type="qml" enabled="yes"
this is the installation summary

```
   Summary of your installation :


   OpenGL gui  : DISABLED : you are missing (libsdl maybe?) libxmu 
   Maemo/Hildon: DISABLED
   Maemo/OSSO: DISABLED
   Garmin IMG  : DISABLED (you don't have libgarmin)
   Plugins:             yes (default)
   Postgresql:          no ( not executable)
   Samplemap:           yes (default)
   NLS Support:         yes (system gettext support)
   Routing:             yes (default)
   Font renderers:
   freetype:          yes (default)
   FriBidi enabled:   yes (default)
   Graphics types: yes (default)
   android:  no (default)
   gtk_drawing_area:  yes (gtk+-2.0 present)
   null:              yes (default)
   qt_qpainter:       yes (Package qt-mt present)
   win32:             no (default)
   OpenGL:            yes (default)
   gd:                no (default)
   sdl:               no (sdl not available)
   GUI types:
   gtk:               yes (gtk+-2.0 present)
   internal:          yes (default)
   win32:             no (default)
   qml:               no (Package QtXml is missing)
   Map types:
   binfile:           yes (default)
   filter:             yes (default)
   mg:                yes (default)
   shapefile:         yes (default)
   textfile:          yes (default)
   Bindings:
   dbus:              yes (default)
   python:            no (/usr//python2.6/config/Makefile or /usr/include/python2.6  /Python.h missing)
  OSD types:
  core:              yes (default)
  Plugins:
  pedestrian:      no (default)
  Speech types:
   android:           no (default)
  cmdline:           yes (default)
  dbus:              yes (dbus binding present)
  espeak:            no (default)
  speech_dispatcher: yes (default)
  Vehicle types:
  android:           no (default)
  demo:              yes (default)
  file:              yes (default)
  gpsd:              yes (default)
  gpsd_dbus:         yes (dbus binding present)
  gypsy:             no (package gypsy missing)
  maemo:             no (default)
  null:              no (default)
  wince:             no (default)
  iphone:            no (default)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to ask in the Navit community; http://www.navit-project.org/